# C++- Code not working to alternate lines when writing on a text file

Tags: c++, string, file, text

I need to create a program that reads strings from two different files and write these strings on a new file. The thing is, it must alternate both files, meaning that it should write a line from one file, and then one line from the other, and so on.

I'm having a problem with my code, it writes the first line of the first file, and then it writes all lines from the second file.
Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

```
do {

    getline(archivo1, sLinea);
    archivoS << sLinea << endl;
    getline(archivo2, sLinea2);
    archivoS << sLinea2 << endl;

   } while (!archivo1.eof() && !archivo2.eof());
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. [Works for me](http://rextester.com/RMVUDT67589)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks correct and should work under normal circumstances. This might be a problem with the encoding of the second file, where the newline characters are not being recognised as such on your platform, which could result in the entire second file being interpreted as a single line by the C++ standard library.

Windows (CR+LF), Unix/Linux (LF), and Mac (CR) each have different conventions for newlines. Search about the carriage return and line feed characters across platforms to learn more about this topic.

To identify if this is the issue, try running the code on two separate copies of the first file to see if it produces the expected output?

If newline encoding is your issue, you will either need to convert the second file to use your platform's newline encoding (you can use a tool like Notepad++ to easily do this) or incorporate logic which controls for this into your program.

Answer (score 0):

Check your second file. In all likelihood it does not contain the line delimiter "\n" , per line. There may be only one at the end